# Entity Framework Core - One Transaction for multiple API-REST-Requests

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, entity-framework-core

Currently I'm trying to create integration tests to test my .net core REST-API. I don't want to get the test data stored in database finally. One integration test sends multiple HTTP-Requests.

My idea was to start a global transaction before I do the first HTTP Request and finally do an rollback.
But I can't find any way how to store the transaction globally.
Is there a way?

Following my code of the "transactionRepository" where I tried to store the transaction globally:

```cs
public class TransactionRepository : ITransactionRepository
    {
        private static IDbContextTransaction TRANSACTION;
        private readonly Context _context;

        public TransactionRepository(Context context)
        {
            _context = context;
        }

        public void Commit()
        {
            if(TRANSACTION == null)
            {
                throw new ValidationException($"There is no transaction");
            }
            TRANSACTION.Commit();
        }

        public void Rollback()
        {
            if(TRANSACTION == null)
            {
                throw new ValidationException($"There is no open transaction");
            }
            TRANSACTION.Rollback();
        }

        public void Begin()
        {
            if(TRANSACTION != null)
            {
                throw new ValidationException($"already opened");
            }
            TRANSACTION = _context.Database.BeginTransaction();
        }
    }
```

then I call following URLs:

1. POST /transaction/begin //Start Transaction
2. POST /myentity //CREATE
3. PUT /myentity //UPDATE
4. POST /transaction/rollback

But finally all data gets stored in database despite the opened transaction.

Does anyone has an idea what I'm doing wrong respectively if it is possible to have one transaction for multiple API-Requests anyway?

Comment: I know mocking is not considered good practice in integration tests but instead of mocking the entire application to use one huge transaction, I think you should just mock the database to use an in-memory one so when your tests are done the in-memory database is removed or you should just create a whole integration test environment (on the server or locally) and add the cleaning/setup of the database in the testing tool.

Comment: What does this code have to do with data access or HTTP calls apart from the misuse of transactions and the apparent attempt to use the "generic repository" **anti**pattern? Were you trying to control local database transactions from a remote machine? That's called a distributed transaction and simply can't be done using HTTP. It requires specialized transaction managers like MS DTC. Besides, a DbContext is a Unit-of-Work that's only supposed to have **very limited lifetime**, no longer than a single request

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I was just thinking the same that the DbContext should only live for 1 request. (I suppose he could mock the registration to singleton and then this may work, but that is just wrong) imho.

Comment: `it is possible to have one transaction for multiple API-Requests anyway?` why do you need one to begin with? What are you trying to do? It's already obvious you're using an *anti*pattern for data access - there's [no need for repositories and Unit-of-Work with EF Core](https://gunnarpeipman.com/ef-core-repository-unit-of-work/). If. you wanted to implement a *business* transaction, you'd need completely different mechanisms. Businesses processes don't have commit and rollback. You can't rollback a sale or money transfer, you can *reverse* it or cancel it

Comment: In any case, what you seem to be getting is [WS-Transaction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WS-Transaction), a standard to create ACID-like transactions over Web Services that was essentially abandoned by 2010-ish because it didn't scale and was too expensive to implement, and doesn't even fit how business processes really work. An airline or e-Commerce site doesn't roll back a cancelled order.

Comment: One of the main problems with any distributed transaction system is how to get all services to agree that a transaction is committed or rolled back. You can't just make an HTTP POST to commit. What if the connection goes down or is delayed? How does the sender know that the server committed? And how does the *server* tell the sender? How does the server know the sender acknowledged? In a datacenter with *very* low latency you can use 2PC (two phase commit) for that. Over the internet, with lost connections and calls, it proved impossible

Comment: I think you can use caching concept instead of repositories for your testing, If you don't have a proper testing environment for executing test cases, It's will help to you executed your test case.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos, the link you gave, to me, almost seems to need even further design solutions for inevitable problems. The best thing about providing repositories is you can abstract away the underlying ORM. It's a well-known best practice to not litter your code with ORM-specific code or depend on their classes directly. It's not the only solution for that but it's simple and everywhere in the wild.

Comment: @ChiefTwoPencils you didn't read it then. Or tried to read it just to discredit it. The problems with "generic repositories" are well known: [Repository is the new Signleton](https://ayende.com/blog/3955/repository-is-the-new-singleton) was written by Ayende, at the time the maintainer of NHibernate, back in 2009. In fact what you call a Repository isn't even that, it's a Data Access Object. It *does* litter your code with needless transactions just to bring back the UoW semantics it broke. In turn, this breaks the disconnected operation semantics and results in blocking and bad scalability

Comment: @ChiefTwoPencils since the ORM already is a generic repository, what's needed is a *specialized* repository to serve **specific bounded contexts**. One use case/scenario needs a different Customer or Product entity than the other. There's no reason to use the same DbContext with the same entities for all use cases. A DbContext is a UoW, not a database model. A "generic" repository just aliases DbSet at best. A specialized repository makes it a lot easier to work with the ORM for a specific context

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos, wrong; I did read it and I've read countless other rantings on the matter; the argument is nothing new.

Comment: Hi bro. You should consider the Unit of Work Pattern. The idea is keep the database work in one place. You can refer this article for more detail
https://www.danylkoweb.com/Blog/a-better-entity-framework-unit-of-work-pattern-DD

Comment: @PhạmThếHùng a DbContext is a Unit-of-Work already. The question is about something different though - long-running business transactions controlled by HTTP calls,implemented as a single database transaction. Something that always fails in web apps because each request is handled by different objects and threads